# Is it possible to create table of contents in code comment?

Tags: javascript, php, comments, phpstorm, tableofcontents

I have a file where I put all useful functions I may use in the future.

It becoming a problem to find something quick in this file so I created a comment above, like this:

```
/**
 * My functions:
 * #1 - function one
 * #2 - function two
 * #3 - function three
 * ...
 */
```

I put #1, #2, #3 to the each function description.
Then I can easily find them in editor. But is there a special functionality, so I could create a table of contents so just by clicking I would go to the desired function.

Languages I use mostly are: JavaScript and PHP, and editors are PhpStorm and Sublime Text.

Comment: You are most likely looking for PHPDoc. You can generate documentation based on comment annotations in the source. http://www.phpdoc.org/ Alternately, CTAG support in your editor might help you out.

Comment: PhpStorm has the ability to search for function/method declaration. In   current file scope it would be `Navigate | File Structure`

Comment: @LazyOne not exactly table of contents but very close. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need table of contents if editor will list all stuff in current file any way hence defeating the need in such TOC. If you do not like using popup tool window -- use Structure panel.

Comment: @LazyOne because sometimes this file also contains snippets of code that are not in any function. I can make them into function thought...